# Rails Devise Omniauth 1.0 with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm following the steps in Ryan Bates Railscaast #235, however, I'm trying to integrate Facebook instead of twitter.

GemFile

```
gem "omniauth-facebook", :git => "git://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook.git"
```

Authentication Controller

```
 def create
   render :text => request.env["rack.auth"].to_yaml
  end
```

Omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'ID', 'Secret'
end
```

Routes

```
  devise_for :users

  resources :authentications
    match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'
```

I'm testing this using http://localhost:3000 and have this designated as my facebook web site URL.  When I enter localhost:3000/auth/facebook I'm prompted by facebook successfully, however, I'm redirected to:
http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback?code= and the following page content:

--- !!null ...

My question is where is at least the facebook email address?  Or as a noob am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In your Authentication Controller, change the following line:

```
render :text => request.env["rack.auth"].to_yaml
```

to

```
render :text => request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
```

Also take a look at [RailsCast Episode 241 - Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) which Ryan Bates has updated to work with OmniAuth 1.0